# Possible to elegantly convert std:vector to cliext::vector or cli::array<T>?

Tags: stl, vector, c++-cli

How's that for a catchy title?

I need to convert back and forth from a CLR compliant type, like an array, and a std::vector type.

Are there any adapter methods out there, or should I just keep copying it in and out each time I call one of my native methods?

There are some interesting methods for converting between the cliext STL variant classes and CLR types, but I'm at a loss for how to get the standard vector into the STL types without a for next loop.

This is what I'm doing all over the place in this project:

```
vector<double> galilVector = _galilClass->arrayUpload(marshal_as<string>(arrayName));
List<double>^ arrayList = gcnew List<double>();

// Copy out the vector into a list for export to .net
for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < galilVector.size(); i++) 
{
    arrayList->Add(galilVector[i]);
}

return arrayList->ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of "doing that all over the place", why don't you make that logic into a reusable function?

Something like

```
template<typename T>
generic<typename S>
std::vector<T> marshal_as(System::Collections::Generic::ICollection<S>^ list)
{
  if (list == nullptr) throw gcnew ArgumentNullException(L"list");
  std::vector<T> result;
  result.reserve(list->Count);
  for each (S& elem in list)
    result.push_back(marshal_as<T>(elem));
  return result;
}
```

Remember to use vector's `swap` member function to quickly move the elements into the vector you want to hold them, if you just assign then a zillion copy constructors would be called.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the swap reference above?  I don't use STL much.

Comment: The assignment operator and copy constructor for `std::vector` both do a deep copy.  So `std::vector<string> xyz = marshal_as<string>(SomeCollectionOfSystemString);` will convert all the .NET string into C++ strings inside `marshal_as`, then copy all the strings from the temporary vector returned by `marshal_as` into xyz.  If instead you did `std::vector<string> xyz; xyz.swap(marshal_as<string>(SomeCollectionOfSystemString));` then the array of strings which is the internal data storage of the temporary vector is transferred to `xyz` and no extra copies are made.

Comment: In C++0x, move constructor and move assignment syntax will make both methods efficiently turn over ownership of the vector content instead of copying it.  Until then, though, calling swap is a common idiom to steal the content from a temporary.

Comment: My compiler crashes when I try to compile the above code. I think I will just have to implement the non-generic methods :-( until I have more time to troubleshoot it.

Comment: That's entirely possible.  A simple thing to try would be to make both `S` and `T` template arguments and not use generics.

Comment: How to use this function? I tried         std::vector<std::string> result = marshal_as<std::vector<string>>(mylist); and I get compiler error

Comment: @EdwinVivekN: Did you try the examples I already gave in my comment above?

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading the code or the original question or both. My understanding of the original question is the OP has a std::vector<T> already and they need a cli::array<T>. The code appears to start with the cli::array<T> and return a std::vector<T>. In other words, the code does exactly the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: @BenKey: The question begins (if you skip over the first line of fluff) "I need to **convert back and forth**" so both directions were interesting to OP

Answer (score 2):

```
IList<int>^ Loader::Load(int id)
{
    vector<int> items;
    m_LoaderHandle->Loader->Load(id, items);

    cliext::vector<int> ^result = gcnew cliext::vector<int>(items.size());
    cliext::copy(items.begin(), items.end(), result->begin());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```html
cliext::vector<Single> vec_cliext; 
     
std::vector<float> vec_std;

cliext::vector<Single>::iterator it = vec_cliext.begin(); 
for (; it != vec_cliext.end(); ++it)
{
 float temp = *it;
 vec_std.push_back(temp);
}
```